# Carrying forward the transactionManager from outer @Transactional attribute

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

Say I have this setup:

MyDAO1.java:

```
public class MyDAO1 {
    @Resource(name="myLibraryDAO")
    private MyLibraryDAO myLibraryDAO;
    @Transactional(value="myTransactionManager")
    public void foo() { 
        myLibraryDAO.bar();
    }
}
```

MyLibraryDAO.java

```
public class MyLibraryDAO {
    @Resource(name="myUtilityDAO")
    private MyUtilityDAO myUtilityDAO;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void bar() {
        myUtilityDAO.baz();
    }
}
```

In my spring context file, I am not specifying any default transaction-manager in my tx:annotation-driven directive (primarily because I have other data sources and their transaction managers and I don't want to declare one as the default). MyDAO1 and MyLibraryDAO operate on potentially different datasources (and I am not looking to do any XA-style management) and the requirement is that MyLibraryDAO not operate on the existing transaction (if one exists). To solve this, I have used propagation=REQUIRES_NEW.

Now, when I use @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW), I want to know if there is a way that I can have it reuse *the attributes of* the transaction manager of the outer transaction if available? Since the MyLibraryDAO is intended to be a library and hence devoid of any specific usage related information, what is the best way to have it configured at runtime (based on the invoking DAO)?

Right now, it plainly fails when looking for the default transaction manager bean named "transactionManager".

I know I might be sounding confused, but would appreciate if someone asked more pointed questions.

Thanks!

Comment: TX interceptor simply needs a well defined transaction manager, otherwise it can not operate. There is no OUTER / INNER TX manager, but TX manager used by the TX aspect / interceptor.

Comment: @PavelHoral thanks for the comment. I have modified the question to indicate that I needed the attributes of the transaction manager of the "outer" transaction. In the case of a transaction being configured as REQUIRES_NEW, I wanted to know if there is a way wherein the TransactionAttribute for the "inner" transaction can reuse the TransactionAttribute properties from the "outer" transaction. More specifically, if one can implement a org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSource (say PropogationTxAttributeSource) that passes on properties from the "outer" txn?

Comment: Now it makes sense to me... removing downvote and upvoting.